# How to Create a Unique Int for Each Person Added

Tags: java, android

I am working on an app right now where a person will be able to add different people to a list and then reuse those people. After they select a person, they can move on to a screen where you check a bunch of boxes such as "carrot" or "potato". Each person that is added needs to have a unique "carrot" or "potato" int so it can be used later to count up all the amount of times that carrot or potato has been checked off.

How do I go about doing the int creating whenever a new person is added? I know what to do from there but I honestly have no idea what to do about this.

So if I have a person created named "nick" I can create an int called "carrotnick". I need that id to be displayed later on without me knowing that there is a nick on the end, only the carrot part. So it can't be completely random. Still needs to be displayed later on somehow.

Comment: I have tried attaching a string with the name of the person the end of the int whenever that person is created but I can't get it to work.

Comment: you need to have a unique int id?

Comment: Yes, but it needs to be displayed later. So if I have a person created named "nick" I can create an int called "carrotnick". I need that id to be displayed later on without me knowing that there is a nick on the end, only the carrot part. So it can't be completely random. Still needs to be displayed later on somehow.

Comment: Do you have a database behind this app? If so, add a table in your DB for "UserVegetables" which has two columns - the User ID and the Vegetable ID. Each should be a foreign key to the unique ID fields in your Users and Vegetables tables, respectively. That creates a relationship between the user and the vegetables they chose. In entity-relationship design / database normalisation this is generally known as a "many-to-many" style relationship. Then to build the "CarrotNick" type of string you can simply run a SQL query to fetch the user name and all the vegetables they selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sqlite and a table with auto incremental field so for each person which be added to table there is a unique id so you can either get ids after app restarted

Comment: Thank you, will I be able to use that later then. If I have a "nick" person, I need to have a summary of all the ints for nick later on. With a random id I wouldn't be able to do this right? Maybe not. Could you provide a link to a tutorial for something like you are suggesting?

Comment: definitely data which need to be fetched later are saved on sqlite and there are a lot of tools to manipulate data.

Comment: if you search sqlite in stackflow there are a lot of tutorials

Comment: How do I go about doing this all this my android application though.... The checkboxes need to add 1 to the int if it is checked and not add if it is not checked.

Comment: and also i think there is no need for a random id if you want to be unique an auto incremental field grantee you to give you a unique id .

Comment: Yes, I don't want it random, I want to unique like with a carrot checkbox and a nick person then carrotnick

Comment: try to have good knowledge about content provider and see stackflow about questions .

Comment: Is it allright that I have around 40 ints? It is a lot and from the tutorial, I am seeing I have to list all of those in parenthesis?